# current package keyword in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, package, default

1.Is there a keyword to refer to the current package that you are working in Java. Like we have "this" to refer to the current object. So , is there something similar for a package?

2.Also if the current class that I am working on is in a directory which has other classes,and my class has no package statement, then it will be in the default package. So, is there any way to import rest of the classes in the directory. I know that we can specify the classpath while compiling, but is there any way to do it using imports ?

Comment: For (1) - not it is not available. However you can use `this.getClass().getPackage()` to get the package. Please do not ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: ok thanks, yup will take care next time

Comment: [JLS #3.9 Keywords](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9).

Answer (score 2):

1. No, there is not
2. No, classes in the default package can't be imported. That's one of the reasons you should never put your classes in the default package. The obvious reason is that, if every library did that, you would end up with conflicts between classes.

Comment: You should add the this.getClass().getPackage() as a useful alternative - even if it's not a keyword - but OP aksed for "something similar"

Comment: It's unclear what the user would like to do with such a keyword. I'll add this if it makes sense.

Comment: He could do whatever you can do with the result of Class.getPackage().

Answer (score 0):

The first one

No `keyword` like `this` to get `package name`, but you can get `package name` by `java reflection`, like the following code

```
package com.netease.unitest.controller;

public class GenTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GenTest.class.getPackage().getName());

    }
}
```

the output is

```
com.netease.unitest.controller
```

you can get more details in the following link

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html